# Varying results using multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost, future

I'm trying to optimize the running time of my C++ code by utilizing multiple threads. I have tried a few different solutions.

I have this code using boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

void Test::boost_worker_task() {
    char new_state[3][3];
    MyEngine::random_start_state(new_state);
    MyEngine::solve_game(new_state);
    ++games_solved_counter;
}

void Test::run(const unsigned int games_to_solve, const bool use_mul_thread) {
    MyEngine::init_rand();
    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const unsigned int num_threads = use_mul_thread ? std::thread::hardware_concurrency() : 1;
    std::cout << "Using " << num_threads << " threads to solve " << games_to_solve << " games" << std::endl;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool(num_threads);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < games_to_solve; ++i) {
            io_service.post([] { return Test::boost_worker_task(); });
    }

    // Run and wait for all tasks to complete
    io_service.run();
    pool.join();

    const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> elapsed = end - start;

    std::cout << "Solved " << games_solved_counter << " games!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() / 1000.0 << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " milliseconds\n" << std::endl;
}
```

As well as this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <future>

std::atomic<int> games_solved(0);

void TestMulThread::worker_task(const unsigned int num_iterations, std::mutex& games_solved_mutex) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
        char new_state[3][3];
        MyEngine::random_start_state(new_state);
        MyEngine::solve_game(new_state);

        ++games_solved;
    }
}
void TestMulThread::run(const unsigned int total_games_to_solve) {
    MyEngine::init_rand();
    const auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const unsigned int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    const unsigned int games_per_thread = total_games_to_solve / num_threads;
    const unsigned int remaining_games = total_games_to_solve % games_per_thread;
        std::cout << "Using " << num_threads << " threads to solve " << total_games_to_solve << " games" << std::endl;

    // Distribute the remaining games
    std::vector<unsigned int> games_for_each_thread(num_threads, games_per_thread);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < remaining_games; ++i) {
        games_for_each_thread[i]++;
    }

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    std::mutex games_solved_mutex;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, worker_task, games_for_each_thread[i], std::ref(games_solved_mutex)));
    }

    for (auto& future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }

    const auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
    std::cout << "Solved " << games_solved << " games!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed_time / 1000.0 << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed_time << " milliseconds\n" << std::endl;
}
```

My issues are twofold:

1. The boost version is running much slower than the second code. It's even running slower than using a simple for loop and not trying to utilize several threads. I understand that trying to run tasks in parallel can lead to overhead of different sorts but the second code is running super fast and I would like to understand why.
2. The second code snippet is running really fast when using Visual studio (compiling with Release and -O2 flags as C++ optimization), but when I compile and run the same code on my Linux machine using g++ it's again running slower than using a for loop to run the same amount of games. I've tried compiling with a few different settings, like:

```
g++ -O2 -o test Test.cpp -std=c++20 -lpthread
g++ -O2 -o test Test.cpp -std=c++20 -pthread
```

Any ideas as to why this is the case?

I've verified that the fast version is indeed solving the tasks which also gets noticeable when increasing the games_to_solve since it will then take a longer time to run.

Comment: Have you tried compiling g++ under Windows and see what the results are?

Comment: Is that the *real* code?  It appears to have an unmatched `#endif` within the definition of `TestMulThread::worker_task`.

Comment: You should not use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to measure performance (wall clock time), but a `std::chrono::steady_clock`. The former is not guaranteed to be monotonic. Besides, I am wondering if you really measure the wall clock time with the former and not the CPU time (i.e. parallel time)... Besides did you check `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` is the same in both case? Running too many thread slow things down.

Comment: I also found that mutexes can behave differently between OS but also between the GNU/MinGW and Windows/MSVC stack (both on Windows). It looks like you use them but you did not sent the real code. Who know what `MyEngine::random_start_state` and `MyEngine::solve_game` do (due to the possible use of globals like `games_solved`).

Comment: You should start your timing after the "Using" message is sent to `std::cout` (in both versions). No need to have I/O potentially affect your timing.

Comment: What is the purpose of `games_solved_mutex`? I see it defined, passed as a parameter to `worker_task`, then ignored.

Comment: Your question is missing a statement that the output is correct. You don't need to go into great detail (just "The output is correct for each version."), but it would be reassuring to know that the fast version is not fast because it skips all the work...

Comment: I've verified that the fast version is indeed solving the tasks which also gets noticeable when increasing the games_to_solve since it will then take a longer time to run.
I tried to only include the relevant parts in the post - i.e. the thread / task overhead which is the only code that differs between the code snippets.
games_solved_mutex can be ignored since I've verified that using / not using it has no significant affect.

Comment: @JonasÖrnfelt I wrote that **your question** is missing that statement. Comments are not part of your question, and they are subject to disappear at any time leaving no history. *(I have copied the information into the question, so this is for your future reference.)*

Answer (score 0):

The first program never uses the threadpool. Except to join.

If you fix at least the first, the performance matches between the two:

> I've also removed cruft that didn't get used or was unrelated to the question. Also reworded the chrono hell to be more elegant. Notably shifted the random generator to each task because they are NOT threadsafe! Finally renamed "threads" to "tasks" in the `std::async` version because `std::async` guarantees little about thread scheduling in the standard.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16028408be1f39b1)**

- File `test.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <atomic>

   namespace Test {
       static void boost_worker_task();
       static void run(unsigned, bool);

       static inline std::atomic_uint games_solved_counter{0};
   }; // namespace Test

   namespace TestMulThread {
       static void worker_task(unsigned);
       static void run(unsigned);

       static inline std::atomic_uint games_solved{0};
   }; // namespace TestMulThread

   struct MyEngine {
       using State = char[3][3];
       static void init_rand();
       static void random_start_state(State&);
       static void solve_game(State&);
   };
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "test.h"
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <random>
   #include <thread>
   using namespace std::chrono_literals;
   static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

   void MyEngine::init_rand() {}
   void MyEngine::random_start_state(State&) {}
   void MyEngine::solve_game(State&) {
       thread_local static std::mt19937                  prng{std::random_device{}()};
       thread_local static std::uniform_int_distribution work(3, 8);
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms * work(prng));
   };

   void TestMulThread::worker_task(unsigned num_iterations) {
       MyEngine::init_rand();
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
           char new_state[3][3];
           MyEngine::random_start_state(new_state);
           MyEngine::solve_game(new_state);

           ++games_solved;
       }
   }

   void TestMulThread::run(unsigned total_games_to_solve) {
       auto     start_time      = now();
       unsigned num_tasks       = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
       unsigned games_per_task  = total_games_to_solve / num_tasks;
       unsigned remaining_games = total_games_to_solve % games_per_task;
       std::cout << "Using " << num_tasks << " tasks to solve " << total_games_to_solve << " games" << std::endl;

       // Distribute the remaining games
       std::vector buckets(num_tasks, games_per_task);
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i < remaining_games; ++i) {
           buckets[i]++;
       }

       std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

       for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_tasks; ++i)
           futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, worker_task, buckets[i]));

       for (auto& future : futures)
           future.get();

       auto elapsed = now() - start_time;
       std::cout << "Solved " << games_solved << " games!" << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed / 1.s << " seconds" << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed / 1ms << " milliseconds\n" << std::endl;
   }

   void Test::boost_worker_task() {
       char new_state[3][3];
       MyEngine::random_start_state(new_state);
       MyEngine::solve_game(new_state);
       ++games_solved_counter;
   }

   void Test::run(unsigned games_to_solve, bool threaded) {
       auto const start = now();

       unsigned num_threads = threaded ? std::thread::hardware_concurrency() : 1;
       std::cout << "Using " << num_threads << " threads to solve " << games_to_solve << " games" << std::endl;

       boost::asio::thread_pool pool(num_threads);

       for (unsigned i = 0; i < games_to_solve; ++i)
           post(pool, Test::boost_worker_task);

       // Run and wait for all tasks to complete
       pool.join();

       auto elapsed = now() - start;

       std::cout << "Solved " << games_solved_counter << " games!" << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed / 1.s << " seconds" << std::endl;
       std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed / 1ms << " milliseconds\n" << std::endl;
   }

   int main() { //
       auto N = 10'000u;
       Test::run(N, true);
       TestMulThread::run(N);
   }
  ```

Prints, online:

```
Using 4 threads to solve 10000 games
Solved 10000 games!
Elapsed time: 14.0106 seconds
Elapsed time: 14010 milliseconds

Using 4 tasks to solve 10000 games
Solved 10000 games!
Elapsed time: 14.2782 seconds
Elapsed time: 14278 milliseconds
```

And locally for me:

```
Using 8 threads to solve 10000 games
Solved 10000 games!
Elapsed time: 6.96683 seconds
Elapsed time: 6966 milliseconds

Using 8 threads to solve 10000 games
Solved 10000 games!
Elapsed time: 7.04044 seconds
Elapsed time: 7040 milliseconds
```